# Python function get *arg name

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a python function

```
def func(a, b, *c, **d):
    pass
```

I can get the names of arguments:

```
>>> print(func.__code__.co_varnames)
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

But how do I know, that c is *args and d is **kwargs??

Comment: This looks like XY problem. What is the purpose of knowing that? What difference would it make to you if you have a function `def func(a, b, *c, **d)` that you call e.g. `func(1, 2, 3, 4, foo='spam', bar='eggs')` and another one `def func(a, b, c, d)` that you call like `func(1, 2, (3, 4), {'foo':'spam', 'bar':'eggs'})`

Comment: d is going to be name: value pairs. type(d) = dictionary. c will not be

Comment: Nit: you are getting the names of the *parameters*. Arguments are the values *assigned* to the parameter names when the function is called.

Comment: I need to know it without calling a function. I need a function that takes function as argument and returns *args parameter name and **kwargs parameter name.

Comment: `inspect` module is your best option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, this information is only accessible via the `Signature` object returned by `inspect.signature`. Where *that* function gets the information, I do not know. (It may be something stored by the implementation that is not otherwise exposed at the Python level.)

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.signature(func).parameters['a'].kind
<_ParameterKind.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD: 1>
>>> inspect.signature(func).parameters['c'].kind
<_ParameterKind.VAR_POSITIONAL: 2>
>>> inspect.signature(func).parameters['d'].kind
<_ParameterKind.VAR_KEYWORD: 4>
```

---

If you look at the definition of [`_signature_from_function`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/inspect.py#L2276), you'll see it determines the kind by looking at the flags in `func.__code__.co_objects` and applying some left-to-right logic on the names you see in `func.__code__.co_varnames`.